# Let R a ring with subring $\mathbb{C}$. Show there is no homomorphism $R\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R a ring with subring $\mathbb{C}$. Show there is no ring homomorphism $\phi:R\to\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt: every ring homomorphism from a field to a non-zero ring is injective. So we can consider the restriction of $\phi$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

If $\phi(i)=r$, then $r^4=1\implies r^2=\pm1$.
 $r^3=-r\implies r(r^2-1)=0\implies r=0 $ or $r=\pm 1$. In any case, $\phi$ is not injective. QED

Is this right?

Comment: But why should $\phi$ be injective?  If $R=\mathbb C \times \mathbb R$ then we can just project onto the second factor.  Yes, it is not injective on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Well, the previous question was: show that any ring homomorphism $k\to R$ from a field to a non-zero ring is injective, so since the subring is also a field, then the restriction of $\phi$ must be injective, and I (think) I showed that whatever it is, it cannot be injective?

Comment: My error.  I keep forgetting that the inclusion map for direct product of rings is not a ring homomorphism.  That is, in my example, the obvious inclusion of $\mathbb C$ into the direct product is not a ring homomorphism.  Thus it is not a counterexample to your claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you went a little off course.

Starting as you did, let $r=\phi(i)$.

Since $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism, we must have $\phi(1) = 1$, hence
$$i^2+1 = 0 \implies \phi(i^2+1) = 0 \implies r^2 + 1 = 0$$
contradiction, since for any $r \in \mathbb{R}, r^2+1 > 0$.

Hence there is no such homomorphism.

Comment: Complex numbers were a mistake

Comment: @George: I don't follow.